# Coding a general function to: Disable a tkinter widget with a checkbutton

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to write a function to disable a widget in a tkinter program depending on the value of a checkbutton. I want this function to be general: That is, I can pass it the widget and associated check variable and it will disable the widget (if the variable is checked the right way).

Here is an abstracted version of my code

```
import tkinter
class App:
    def __init__(self,root):
        widg = tkinter.Scale(root,from_=0,to=100)
        checkvar  = tkinter.IntVar()
        checker = tkinter.Checkbutton(root,variable=checkvar,command=self.check(var,checkvar))
        widg.grid()
        checker.grid()

        widg.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        widg.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)

    def check(self,widget,var):
        if var.get()==1:
            widget.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        elif var.get()==0:
            widget.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)


m = tkinter.Tk()
f=App(m)
```

It is intended to function such that clicking the checkbutton triggers the callback - check - with the parameters of the widget and the check variable. Then it will evaluate whether the widget should be on or off and change its state accordingly. There are no errors but the state doesn't change. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to my friend JB for helping me with this.

As user Axe319 suggested, the problem is just that tkinter doesn't expect to pass any parameters. It is possible to work around this by using a lambda function. The line that defines the checker variable, in my original post line 8, can be rewritten as such:

```
self.checker = tkinter.Checkbutton(root,variable=checkvar,command=lambda:self.check(self.widg,checkvar))
```

and it will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The command argument simply takes the uncalled function so passing arguments to it takes some workaround.

So it expects `self.check` rather than `self.check()` since the widget will call the function later.

I've found that using partial is a workaround for passing the arguments.

```
import tkinter
from functools import partial

class App:
    def __init__(self,root):
        widg = tkinter.Scale(root,from_=0,to=100)
        checkvar  = tkinter.IntVar()
        checker = tkinter.Checkbutton(root,variable=checkvar,command=partial(self.check, widg, checkvar))
        widg.grid()
        checker.grid()

        widg.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        widg.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)

    def check(self,widget,var):
        if var.get()==1:
            widget.configure(state=tkinter.DISABLED)
        elif var.get()==0:
            widget.configure(state=tkinter.NORMAL)


m = tkinter.Tk()
f=App(m)
m.mainloop()
```